# Is a stored procedure call inside a SQL Server trigger implictly thread safe and atomic?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers, atomic

I have a SQL Server trigger. To be honest, I'm not quite sure if triggers implicitly follow `ACID` (`Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability`), but my trigger, at the moment, doesn't do anything particularly complex.

Now, I want to call a stored procedure from within the trigger. I have `TRANSACTION` surrounding the stored procedure call and an `INSERT` statement.

My question is: if a trigger, sans stored procedure call, is thread safe and atomic -- at least in part due to the `TRANSACTION` -- will the stored procedure call be implicitly thread safe and atomic?

Here's what the trigger looks like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [triggerInsert_Foobar] 
ON [Foobar]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Turns on rollack if T-SQL statement raises a run-time error
    SET XACT_ABORT ON

    -- Start new transaction
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        -- Insert statement for trigger
        INSERT INTO Foo ( Col1, Col2 )
            SELECT 
                RTRIM ( LTRIM ( Col1 ) ), 
                Col2
            FROM 
                INSERTED

    -- Call stored procedure (takes no parameters)
    EXECUTE sp_executesql N'FoobarApp_DoSomething'

    -- Complete transaction
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END;
```

Thank you, kindly, for your help.

**Additional question**

This question is being poised after a few responses already (thank you). I apologize in advance.

Does my trigger and the subsequent calling of the stored procedure follow the ACID principle and avoid race conditions and deadlocks? Or, is there something I need to add to my trigger and/or the stored procedure to safeguard against race conditions and deadlocks?

Comment: Be VERY careful using transactions inside a trigger. And since you have no error handling why bother? Keep in mind that ANY insert has an implicit transaction. If your calling code is creating the insert with a transaction and something goes wrong you are going to get an unhandled exception because the tran count will be different when exiting the trigger. I would get rid of the transaction in here as the insert is already handling the atomic nature of this operation.

Comment: I believe `XCT_ABORT ON` takes care of error handling; it performs a rollback if the transaction fails -- no need to explicitly check TRANCOUNT and rollback. Regarding using transactions in triggers, you're saying the tran count of the trigger call will be different than that of the code inside my transaction I created, correct? If so, I see how that could be an issue. What about the stored procedure call? Is that thread safe and atomic? Thank you for your insight, Sean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The underlying operation and the trigger operation treated as atomic. They both commit in one transaction. From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178110.aspx):

> The trigger and the statement that fires it are treated as a single transaction...

Note that the trigger (and the SP is will call) wont' see the table change that fired the trigger.  It hasn't committed yet.

Comment: Thank you. Interesting. So, the INSERT statement won't actually commit until the trigger has finished? Which means if my stored procedure depends on the table change, this might be the wrong place to put the stored procedure.

Comment: @user3621633, you have to pass value from `INSERTED` into the SP which sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: It's a bit of a personal preference/style thing, but I tend to avoid triggers. They are easy to over look when examining the tables.  For what you are doing, just call the stored proc and have it update the table along with whatever you are doing there.

Comment: @user3621633: if you need to examine the data that the `INSERT` statement has inserted, you should probably use an `AFTER INSERT` trigger, not an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger. In that case, your trigger executes after the insert operation has completed, but still within the transaction of that `INSERT`statement. If you don't like what you see, you can just call `ROLLBACK` and abort the `INSERT` transaction to stop it.

Comment: This is the piece of information i was looking to confirm. I have a scenario where the trigger is affecting records i dont want it to. They answer is... dirty read...