# Isolation level for Select statements in transactions for the same SQL Server trigger/stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers, transactions

This question is related to [Is a stored procedure call inside a SQL Server trigger implictly thread safe and atomic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37303735/is-a-stored-procedure-call-inside-a-sql-server-trigger-implictly-thread-safe-and) so I don't know if I should re-post the same code or not. Be that as it may, here's the deal.

As it stands, the `SQL Server` `trigger` is an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` for the moment. It inserts data into a `table` called `Foo`. Then the trigger calls a `stored procedure`. One part of the stored procedure `selects` the last record inserted into Foo:

```
-- New transaction in stored procedure
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    ...

    DECLARE @FooID INT

    SELECT 
        TOP 1 @FooID = ID
    FROM 
        Foo
    ORDER BY
        ID DESC

    ...

END TRANSACTION
```

Let's say two `INSERT` statements are executed at the same time (let's call the two INSERT transactions T1 and T2 for simplification). That's two simultaneous trigger calls. The trigger and stored procedure are both `atomic` in my case.

But do I need to worry about `isolation` for the `SELECT`statement in the stored procedure? Is it guaranteed that the last record inserted will be correctly selected? Or, could I run into a situation where T1 selects the T2 record and vice-versa?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not write your inserts to use an `OUTPUT` clause, then locally to the trigger determine the highest `ID` that has been produced from that `OUTPUT` and explicitly pass the value to the stored procedure? By the way, you *are* aware that multi-row inserts and updates are a thing, and that triggers are only called *once* for such statements, correct?

Comment: Thank you very much. Well, one reason I'm doing it this way is the stored procedure is versatile, in that it could be called by the trigger or another application. So, I kinda wanted to do a *write-once* approach. And, yes, I'm aware of multi-row and triggers. The data inserted is from a form and will be one insert row per form submission. Thank you, again.

Comment: But your stored procedure, as it currently stands, is *brittle*. It's "guess that the recent history of a particular table is exactly the one that I've been written for and proceed from there". Is that really a good interface? Essentially, the "most recent ID value" is already a *hidden* parameter to that stored procedure

Comment: I see. Well, I thought that, perhaps, because the SP is in the trigger here and inside a transaction, it wouldn't be a guess but a certainty. It would seem that just because it's inside a transaction and a trigger, it doesn't mean the data from the Select statement will be consistent, is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Isolation levels are well covered in the MSDN documentation: [Transaction Isolation Levels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709374%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and they most definitely can affect how the SPs operate. Also, as mentioned yesterday, the SP in the trigger may not see the insert that caused the trigger.

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback! I tested it out yesterday and the SP was able to see the data inserted in the INSTEAD OF trigger. But I'll have to stress test and confirm it is 100% if, say, there are 100 Insert statements. I appreciate the link; I will carefully read through it. I have been doing research on the intricacies of isolation levels. My conclusion was that I could run into problems with the Select statement in the SP, but I wasn't 100% sure, which is why I poised the question here. Based on your post, it would seem I need to be careful with Select in the SP. Thank you, again.